# Date formatted "Jan 2017" not ordering correctly on graphs

Tags: sorting, date

[[image: Here is an image of my data frame]

The dates are formatted like "Jan 2018" or "Oct 2019" ect.

When I try to use this column as the x axis it orders alphabetically in both ggplot2....

ggplot(data = P) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = date, y = Point.Forecast))

and normal plots.....

plot(P$date,P$Point.Forecast)

Comment: Add another column which is a real date being the 1st day of each month, order by that date column. The current column is a string, so it gets ordered as text. **OR** use a string that can be ordered in date sequence,  such as 2017-01 2017-02 2017-03

Comment: Ok is it possible to filter the X axis by like an index column or do I just need to display the date in that other format?

Comment: The easy answer is to use the `2018-01` format, I can't offer much more than this